# What does mean the fields- domain, realm and mechanism in the Authorization Manager of JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance, performance-testing, blazemeter

I am trying to test a website using Jmeter. I recorded the script using the `blazemeter plugin`. While running,it seems that the login is not performed properly. And the all the further scripts fail because of it. I been told to use  the `Authorization manager`, but I am not able to figure out the fields. Kindly help me with these doubts.

What does mean the fields- **domain, realm** and **mechanism** in the Authorization Manager of JMeter?

Comment: Have you done some research befor asking?

Answer (score 1):

If you have been told to use the [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) you should have been told what to put there as well.

HTTP Authorization Manager supports 3 protocol authentication types:

- [Basic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) - in this case you will not need to put there anything. Mechanism should be `BASIC_DIGEST`
- [NTLM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NT_LAN_Manager) - in this case you will need to specify your [Windows Domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_domain) in the "Domain" input, mechanism still `BASIC_DIGEST`
- [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)) - in addition to "Domain" you will need to set your [Kerberos Realm](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/tividd/td/framework/GC32-0803-00/en_US/HTML/plan20.htm)in the "Realm" field.  In this case mechanism would be `KERBEROS`, in addition you will need to perform Kerberos-specific configuration in `jaas.conf` and `krb5.conf` files.

More information: [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter)